# How can I add typing effect on PNG keyboard image in android app?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments, android-animation

I am developing an flip clock alarm app similar to Lost TV series clock. The screen displays a terminal and keyboard and the user typed code is displayed on terminal. The terminal and keyboard are PNG images, how can I let user click buttons on PNG image? by animation or something else?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest not using an image for the keyboard.  The problem with that technique is that you need to know where each key is in order to overlay it with images and effects.  When you take scaling for screen size into account, that's problematic.  And a pain in the neck to keep track of every time the image changes.

A better technique would be to use a single background image and a separate image(s) for the keys-  that way you can easily apply an effect if the key is pressed by applying it when you draw the key image.

Comment: Yes I am applying black screen image in background and keyboard PNG image is in front  but my client wants that the user should be able to click the buttons on keyboard PNG image, how can I get this done?